# Javascript for loop never ends (10^10 itenerations)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a 'for' loop wich have to loop around 10000000000 times so that i get the disered result.
However, it ends up all the time freezing the browser ...
It's not like that 'for' is working infinitly but as i told, it's very long
Is there some way to solve my problem with javascript or i should use another language ?

Comment: 1. Why does it need to iterate so many times? 2. It's probably causing a stack overflow (!)

Comment: It wont be a stack overflow. Iterating in a loop doesn't add to the stack. Most browsers have a limit for how long they will run a javascript event for and you are reaching that limit. If you want to use JavaScript install node and just run it from the terminal.

Comment: JS does freeze the browser and should be used for lighter or shorter applications only.

Comment: Show your code. It's relevant what you're doing within the for loop.

Comment: Try using a sort algo to lighten the load: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html

Comment: Sounds like you need to unwind loops and use webworkers.

Comment: [Here is the link of my code](http://namrouch.olympe.in/scripts/code.txt),
The expected output is 39996941/40000000
I can explain why it should be if necessary

Answer (score 0):

In a compiled language and if you do virtually nothing in the loop, you can achieve 1,000,000,000 iterations a second on a desktop processor. So your loop would take 10 seconds.

If your Javascript environment is interpreted (and not compiled), you probably won't get more than 10,000,000 iterations and your loop will take 1000 seconds (16 minutes).

If you additionally have somewhat more expensive operations within the loop (and Javascript is likely to allocate memory for simple operations, which is expensive), you're in the order of 1,000,000 iterations per seconds and your code takes 10,000 seconds (close to 3 hours).

You might want to think about a better algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are seeing is because javascript is single threaded in the browser. Your for loop is holding on to the thread for the entire time that it is running. The problem is that this thread also handles interactions with the interface. There may be other possibilities, but the two ways that I can think of to fix this would be:

- Use a Web Worker ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)), this solution will not work for older browsers though
- If possible, break your loop into smaller chunks that can be ran using setTimeout. After each chunk is processed, use setTimeout to schedule the next chunk to be processed in say 100ms. You will need to play with the numbers, but that should free up the thread so that it can respond to events. This will make the calculation take longer but should make it so the browser doesn't freeze up.

Answer (score -1):

1. Don't do it. To run this kind of Javascript code in a browser makes no sense. If you **really** want to do this on the client side, you should consider writing some kind of browser extension, where you have more control on the CPU and local storage.
2. You might want to separate that loop in smaller chunks and run them sequentially, with an appropriate progress system. If you are talking about a loop, a multithreaded system will not help you, assuming the result `n+1` is based on the `n` result.
3. Consider using a server-side script with a `queue` or job mechanism and just push notifications to the client. As Teemu said, the time (even in a fast paced situation) is huge.